# Delphi 10.x thru 11.3 IDE misbehavior with second edit window

Tags: delphi, ide, editor

I just updated from 10.x to 11.3, and discover that a very aggravating behavior in the Delphi IDE remains unfixed, and I'm hoping someone can tell me some setting that gets rid of it, or some workaround.

Assuming a new VCL project, with the main IDE (Window 1) set to Form Designer ("Design") tab, and a second (source code) editor open in Window 2.

Now, clicking the Form Designer (Window 1) causes Window 2 to hide its Navigation (Types/Methods) toolbar.

Now click back to the editor in Window 2, at the location in the text you want to edit. That simultaneously causes the Nav toolbar to reappear, displacing the edit control downward, and turning your click into a drag, selecting 2 or 3 lines of text.

Not only is this unwanted, but if not noticed will lead to those lines of text getting deleted when you start to type, which is obviously the very next thing you expect to be able to do after clicking at a particular location.

I would appreciate if someone would chime in with a way to escape from this booby trap.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Appreciate the comment. But right click activates the context menu :-(. And clicking in the header (title bar) works, but then you have to move the mouse over to where you want to edit. As you say, unnatural and tedious when you're doing it a lot.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Also.. reported in 2020, 2021, and again today in issues RSP 27563, 33929 and 41760.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not really using `Navigation Toolbar` you can disable it in [Tools > Options > User Interface > Editor Options > Display](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Display)

Another thing I noticed is that if you don't click directly on a Form or component within design-time window but instead on a white space first then the `Navigation Toolbar` doesn't hide. So this might be a workaround if you are using `Navigation Toolbar` often.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that disable option. Finally some blessed relief!  I do sometimes use that nav bar within longer units, but that convenience pales in comparison to eliminating the *&^%$#$ unwanted select.  It would be nice if we could have a Structure nav tree in the secondary edit windows. (instead of the awkward drip-downs in the nav bar.).